# crear vector dinamico hasta introducir un 0

Tags: array, c, manejo-de-memoria, vectores

Para empezar a conocer como funcionan los vectores dinamicos quería crear uno que fuera aumentando su tamaño hasta que el usuario introdujera un 0 por teclado.
Esto es lo que he escrito:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int *p;
    int i, n;
    int tam = 1;
    
    p = NULL;
    p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * tam); //lo creo de un elemento solo
    
    for(i = 0; p[i] == 0 ; i++){
        printf("n: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n != 0){
            p[i] = n;
            tam++;
            p = (int*) realloc(p, sizeof(int) * tam);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

El problema es que yo empiezo a introducir numeros y no se detiene cuando introduzco el 0.

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes es la condición del `for` que está mal. El `for` da vueltas hasta que la condición no se cumpla. En tu caso hasta que `p[i]` deje de ser `0`. Y eso no es lo que pretendes hacer. Además, solo añades el `n` a `p[i]` cuando no pulsa `0`.

Si inicializas la variable n a un valor que no sea cero, por ejemplo -1, tu for podría quedar así:

```
int n = -1;
for (i = 0; n != 0; i++) {
    printf("n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n != 0) {
        p[i] = n;
        tam++;
        p = (int*)realloc(p, sizeof(int) * tam);
    }
}
free(p);
```

La condición de salida es cuando la `n` sea `0`. Va a dar vueltas mientras n tenga cualquier valor distinto de 0.

Otra cosa importante es liberar la memoria cuando dejas de usarla, ejecutando el `free` que he añadido. Tu programa termina y bueno, el sistema operativo se encargará de liberarlo, pero es bueno acostumbrarse a hacerlo porque cuando tu programa no termine y pierdas el ámbito del puntero, tendrás una pérdida de memoria.

Answer (score 0):

con un while se soluciona el problema

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int *p;
    int i, n;
    int tam = 1;
    
    p = NULL;
    p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * tam); //lo creo de un elemento solo
    
    n = 1;
    i = 0;
    while(n != 0){
        printf("n: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n != 0){
            p[i] = n;
            tam++;
            p = (int*) realloc(p, sizeof(int) * tam);
        }
    i++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```